# How to get zeros from input field in android studio (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I am having a problem, I want for example to take 0001 from input to convert it to 1110 and all I get is 1.

xml:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
             android:id="@+id/binInput"
             android:digits="01"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
             android:inputType="number"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:textSize="20sp"
             android:typeface="sans" />
```

Text is received by
`binInput.text.toString()`

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you show us your code? Does the input field have a fixed length? If so, padding left with zeros could be an option…

Comment: `<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/binInput"
            android:digits="01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:inputType="number"


            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />`

Comment: I tried to search in internet, but i didn't found any solution. input field doesn't have a fixed length.

Comment: If the input field does not have a fixed length, how do you know it should be `0001` and not `0000001`? Do you have any constraint which should be implemented in Kotlin?

Comment: @Tenfour04 if he call 'reversed()' then the output would be '1000' and he wants it to be '1110'. Like converting 0's to 1's and 1's to 0's.

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't read carefully.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is when you are getting the value from the input and not when you are trying to converting it? Testing here, `binInput.text.toString()` returns me "0001". I used this code to convert and it seems to be working fine: `binInput.text.toString().map { '1' - it }.joinToString("")`